# Full screen video sprites

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to create a small project with video sprites, modeled after [this JSFiddle for audio sprites](http://jsfiddle.net/aarongloege/rQv5h/light/).

Playback works as expected: clicking on the relevant buttons play the relevant portions of the video.

Now, however, I would like to incorporate something that would make the video play in full screen (or full window) when the button is pressed or when a key is pressed. The demo [here, for example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) shows an approach where if you click <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the video is playing, it will enter full-screen mode.

I'm not particularly experienced with JavaScript, so it's likely that the solution is staring me right in the face on how to integrate the approach shown in the Mozilla article, but I'm stumped.

Here's what I have right now, which creates the video sprites, as expected:

```js
var videoSprite = document.getElementById('bbb');

// sprite data
var spriteData = {
  full: {
    start: 0,
    length: 595
  },
  tentotwenty: {
    start: 10,
    length: 10
  },
  tentothirty: {
    start: 10,
    length: 20
  },
  fiftytoonefifty: {
    start: 50,
    length: 200
  }
};

// current sprite being played
var currentSprite = {};

// time update handler to ensure we stop when a sprite is complete
var onTimeUpdate = function() {
  if (this.currentTime >= currentSprite.start + currentSprite.length) {
    this.pause();
  }
};
videoSprite.addEventListener('timeupdate', onTimeUpdate, false);

// in mobile Safari, the first time this is called will load the audio. Ideally, we'd load the audio file completely before doing this.
var playSprite = function(id) {
  if (spriteData[id] && spriteData[id].length) {
    currentSprite = spriteData[id];
    videoSprite.currentTime = currentSprite.start;
    videoSprite.play();
  }
};
```

```html
<video id="bbb">
  <source src="https://ia700408.us.archive.org/26/items/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<br />
<br />
<ul>
  <li>
    <button onclick="playSprite('full');">Play full video</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="playSprite('tentotwenty');">Play from 10 to 20 seconds</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="playSprite('tentothirty');">Play from 10 to thirty seconds</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="playSprite('fiftytoonefifty');">Play from 50 to 200 seconds</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any tips on how to extend this to go full screen or full window would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the code which exists in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Watching_for_the_Enter_key) and modify it to have toggle full screen it means when press enter the video can be full screen if it is not and reverse that.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    toggleFullScreen();
  }
}, false);

function toggleFullScreen() {
  var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;      
  if (!state) {
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

You only need to call `toggleFullScreen()` function when buttons is clicked.

> When I press enter it restarts the video. Why??

When you click on the buttons(**you focus on that button**), the video makes full screen and when you press enter again the video exit from full screen mode and then the focused element(**the button which was already clicked**) click again so it restarts the video.

> Now, I understand what happening. What is the solution?

You only need to call `blur()` function to remove focus from the element.

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="playSprite(this,'full');">Play full video</button>
<button onclick="playSprite(this,'tentotwenty');">Play from 10 to 20 seconds</button>
<button onclick="playSprite(this,'tentothirty');">Play from 10 to thirty seconds</button>
<button onclick="playSprite(this,'fiftytoonefifty');">Play from 50 to 200 seconds</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function(currentElement,id) {
   currentElement.blur();
   //your code
}
```

> What is `this`?

Every time, when `playSprite` function is called(`playSprite(this,  YourdesireTime)`), the current clicked element pass to function to understand which button is clicked and remove focus from the clicked element.

> What is different between your answer and  @cviejo's answer?

**My answer**

1. has toggling functionality
2. doesn't reset the video
3. doesn't optimize(I think you don't like to change your code)

**@cviejo's answer**

1. optimize your code

**Note: I don't want to say @cviejo's answer is not good because he really minimize your code.**

**Conclusion**

You can combine my code and @cviejo's code for getting better result.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/BjKMav)

Comment: Great! +1. So if I'm to understand the difference between this approach and the approach in the other answer, this one has the fullscreen action directly linked to the button as well as the enter key. Is that correct?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I'm sorry to replay late. Please, check the updated answer.

Comment: Awesome updates! Thanks a lot. I'm going to play around with this a little more. Hope you don't mind if I wait just a little longer before deciding how to assign the bounty :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto You are welcome. My first goal is to help people. Fell free to accept any answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this! Next step--working out how to extend it for multiple videos and sprite data definitions. (Don't worry, I'll post another question if that's the case.) ;-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto You are welcome. let me know if you have any questions. By the way, I suggest you use jquery instead of javascript. Do you want to convert your code to jquery?

Comment: I honestly have no experience with jquery and only limited experience with javascript, which is why I went with the javascript approach. Of course, it never hurts to learn something new ;-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto I hope [this](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/wMzGoQ?editors=101) can help you. I leave some comments to understand it better. Feel free to ask any question.